# Dynamic DbContext Generation

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, t4, dbcontext

I need to write a web site content management system that makes use of dynamic Entity Framework DbContext generation. As an input I get a custom data types declaration (in xml) that my C# code knows how to parse. On the output, I need to obtain the code for the DbContext that would provide a facility to store the provided data type instances as DbSet's in a database.

I can see there is .tt -> .cs Generator in a form of a plugin for Visual Studio. I can surely create code that would generate an xml-based (I assume it is) .tt template from my custom declaration and then generate a .cs DbContext for this .tt. But how do I run .tt->.cs conversion manually from code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually T4 templates are transformed at design time inside Visual Studio. If you want to use a T4 template at runtime, change the value of the "Custom Tool" property of the .tt's Project item to "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor".

This will make Visual Studio create a C# class from your T4 template that can be instantiated at runtime, where you can pass parameters to it (e.g. your xml type declaration). Calling the "[TransformText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.texttemplating.texttransformation.transformtext.aspx)" will return the actual output code of the T4 template containing the data classes.

In order to use those classes at runtime, too, you would need to compile the output code in memory.